# What are Delegates?

Tags: objective-c

I have several documents and the videos on Stanford that explain it, but I still fail to get my head around what Delegation actually is.

I'm trying to picture them in a real use so I can relate to it.

Are the similar to event hooks? I've used event hooks in some PHP frameworks.

Sometimes I need things explaining in lamans terms before I can go "ah ha, I get it".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In software engineering, the delegation pattern is a design pattern in object-oriented programming where an object, instead of performing one of its stated tasks, delegates that task to an associated helper object.

Read this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29) in detail.